# TrayMenu cannot hide after clicking other place

Tags: qt

I have implemented tray icon menu for QT application. But the tray icon menu would not hide after clicking other places. Following is my code:

```
m_trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
m_trayIconMenu->addAction(m_restoreAction);
m_trayIconMenu->addAction(m_quitAction);
m_trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
m_trayIcon->setContextMenu(m_trayIconMenu);
```

Comment: The trayiconmenu can dissapear if I click my main application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the this pointer as below.Tied you m_trayIconMenu to QSystemTrayIcon instead of parent this pointer.

```
m_trayIconMenu = new QMenu();
m_trayIconMenu->addAction(m_restoreAction);
m_trayIconMenu->addAction(m_quitAction);
m_trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
m_trayIcon->setContextMenu(m_trayIconMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Windows, have to execute another win32 api SetForegroundWindow()

```
SetForegroundWindow(m_trayIconMenu->parent()->winId())
```

Recommend that execute it in slot 'aboutToShow' of QMenu.

This api work for me, you can try.